# Getting Rid of DBO? SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, web-applications, c#-4.0

Just wondered if there was a secret to do something like Database.Security.Users like AdventureWorks DB is setup. Seems no matter what I do to try to setup "Security.Users", I always get the dbo in front of it and have a hell of a time in C# accessing the info. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to create an object called `Security.Users` with a dot? (as opposed to `Users` in the `Security` schema?) That's probably best avoided as you're seeing, but if you are then the best way to quote the name is probably in square brackets, i.e. `[Security.Users]`.

`dbo` is the default database schema name. Unless you've configured a different default schema for your users etc. you can usually just ignore it, although it's still needed if you're referencing another database by name.

Comment: Namespace, or Schema...I am confused now. Do you mean that using Security.Users in C#/whatever might cause issues?

Comment: I think I meant schema not namespace, although a 'schema' in SQL Server acts like a namespace. Edited. Reading your question again I think you do mean a schema called Security so I'd go with SQLMenace's answer.

Answer (score 2):

you first need to create a schema and make that schema the default schema for that user. Examples and more info can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx

Comment: I will check this out...danke

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Wizard to create this, you will always get it.  Write the SQL statements and you should be fine.

Comment: I figured SQL statements would save the day...however, I am attempting to design an app with the Visual Studio 2010 work flow just for the fun of it...so far, no fun :(